# Calling removeChild on the parent element of a selected element completes without error but does not remove child

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to select a group of html elements and delete them from their parent elements. Currently, I get no exceptions when running the code, but the child elements remain on the page. In addition, running the same code in the developer console works without issue.

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
  <img class="example">
</div>
<div id="two">
  <img class="example">
</div>
<div id="three">
  <img class="example">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const getSelector = (input) => {
        if (input.parentElement.id !== '') {
            return input.parentElement.id;
        }
        else {
            return getSelector(input.parentElement);
        }
    }

    if (window.location.href.includes("language_edit")) {
        document.querySelectorAll("img.example").forEach(e => {
                let location = getSelector(e);
                document.querySelector(`#${location}`).innerHTML = e.outerHTML.toString() + document.querySelector(`#${location}`).innerHTML;
                document.querySelector(`#${location}`).firstChild.style.position = "relative";
                e.parentElement.removeChild(e);
        });
    }
}, false);
```

If there is a better way to remove said elements, I would be happy to be told what it is, but I would also like to know if there is an issue with my code regardless.

EDIT: I have updated the code to include more of the original content for clarity.

Comment: Your code works fine ... perhaps `Unrelated code that makes use of the e argument` is failing - note: since 2013, you can use `e.remove()` instead of `e.parentElement.removeChild(e);` to achieve the same result of removing the element

Comment: ^^ one difference is that `removeChild` returns the removed child, but you don't capture the returned value, so there's in effect no difference

Comment: @JaromandaX `e.remove()` is probably better, since it's more direct. I have updated the code with the previously deleted contents in order to help make the problem clearer, but no other errors occur when running it, and the only line that causes any problems is `e.parentElement.removeChild(e)`.

Comment: your code does this `document.querySelector(\`#${location}\`).innerHTML = ...` ... that would remove the element `e` since it's inside the selected element - of course you can't remove an element that no longer exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was able to solve the problem by using the `insertBefore` method to move the node rather than trying to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `outerHTML` of the parent element, the `<img>` element was removed from the DOM and its `parentElement` property became `null`. You can verify that it is no longer attached to the document:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const getSelector = (input) => {
    if (input.parentElement.id !== '') {
      return input.parentElement.id;
    } else {
      return getSelector(input.parentElement);
    }
  }

  document.querySelectorAll("img.example").forEach(e => {
    let location = getSelector(e);
    document.querySelector(`#${location}`).innerHTML = e.outerHTML.toString() + document.querySelector(`#${location}`).innerHTML;
    document.querySelector(`#${location}`).firstChild.style.position = "relative";
    console.log('connected?', e.isConnected);
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <img class="example">
</div>
<div id="two">
  <img class="example">
</div>
<div id="three">
  <img class="example">
</div>
```

Instead, you can `clone` the element, and use `Element#before` or `Element#after` to place it in the correct relative position.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img.example").forEach(img => {
  const clone = img.cloneNode();
  clone.style.position = 'relative';
  img.before(clone);
  console.log(img.parentElement.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <img class="example">
</div>
<div id="two">
  <img class="example">
</div>
<div id="three">
  <img class="example">
</div>
```